# how to fix hover method

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover

I have this image :

[image]

As you can see, there is a red x button created in css. I have created methods for `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`, and when I hover over the green image, I want the red x to appear, which has a delete functionality. The problem is, when I hover on the green image the red cross appears, but when I hover over the red one to press it, it disappears randomly and I don't know why. I need to fix it in react not using mainly css.

code.js:

```js
const handleMouseOver = () => {
    const isToggle = true
    setToggleDiv(isToggle)
}

const handleMouseOut = () => {
    const isToggle = false
    setToggleDiv(isToggle)
}

<div>
    <h3>preview items</h3>
    <div className="image" onMouseEnter={handleMouseOver} onMouseLeave={handleMouseOut}>
        <img src={myUrl} />
        {toggleDiv === true ?
            <div className="delete" type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(myPhotoId)}>
                X
            </div> : null}
        <div>{myPohotTitle}</div>
    </div>
```

css:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.delete {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does a CSS only solution without JS work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `onMouseLeave` with `onMouseOut` and it will work just fine.

**EDIT:**

Even a better way , much easier without any methods:

```js
export default () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>preview items</h3>
            <div className="image"> 
                <img src={myUrl} />
                <div className="delete" type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(myPhotoId)}>
                X
                </div>
                <div>{myPohotTitle}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

and your css

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.delete {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.image:hover > .delete {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event#mouseout_and_mouseleave) there's an explanation of the difference between mouseleave and mouseout

Comment: i did but its still the same when i hover on the red x it disappear