# Render unique divs for each hovered element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

minimum reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hover-example-tu1eu?file=/index.js

I currently have a new element being rendered when either of 2 other elements are hovered over. But i would like to render different things based upon which element is hovered.

In the example below and in the codepen, there are 2 hoverable divs that are rendered; when they are hovered over, it changes the state and another div is rendered. I would like for the *HoverMe2* div to render text "hello2". Currently, whether i hover hoverme1 or 2, they both just render the text "hello".

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class HoverExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseHover = this.handleMouseHover.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isHovering: false
    };
  }

  handleMouseHover() {
    this.setState(this.toggleHoverState);
  }

  toggleHoverState(state) {
    return {
      isHovering: !state.isHovering
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
        >
          Hover Me
        </div>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
        >
          Hover Me2
        </div>
        {this.state.isHovering && <div>hello</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<HoverExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You can achieve that by only using css : [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281453/how-to-fix-hover-method/62281581#62281581)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CevaComic pointed out, you can do this with CSS. But if you want to use React, for example, because your actual problem is more complex, here is the answer.

You will need a way to tell apart the two elements. It could be done with some neat tricks, like setting an unique `id` to each element, passing a custom argument, or something else.

But I would advise against "cool tricks" as it's more difficult to understand what is going on, and the code is more prone to errors. I think the best way it to use a dumb approach of unique functions for unique elements.

Each `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` has to be an unique function (e.g. `handleMouseHover1` and `handleMouseHover2`), and each of those functions need to control unique state (for example, `isHovering1` and `isHovering2`). Then you have to render the element you want based on the state. Of course, for a real-world code, you will probably want to use more descriptive names to make the code more comprehensible. The full code would look something like this.

```
class HoverExample extends Component {
  state = {
    isHovering1: false,
    isHovering2: false
  };

  handleMouseHover1 = () => {
    this.setState(({ isHovering1 }) => ({ isHovering1: !isHovering1 }));
  };

  handleMouseHover2 = () => {
    this.setState(({ isHovering2 }) => ({ isHovering2: !isHovering2 }));
  };

  render() {
    const { isHovering1, isHovering2 } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover1}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover1}
        >
          Hover Me1
        </div>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover2}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover2}
        >
          Hover Me2
        </div>
        {isHovering1 && <div>hello1</div>}
        {isHovering2 && <div>hello2</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, updated example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hover-example-rc3h0

*Note: I have also edited the code to add some syntax sugar which exists with newer ECMAScript versions. Instead of binding the function, you can use the arrow function format, e.g. `fn = () => { ... }`. The arrow function means the `this` context is automatically bound to the function, so you don't have to do it manually. Also, you don't have to initialize `this.state` inside the constructor, you can define it as a class instance property. With those two things together, you do not need the `constructor` at all, and it makes the code a bit cleaner.*

Comment: When you start numbering variable names, you almost certainly need a data structure such as a list or object.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice First, no you do not need a data structure to represent 2 flags, it's just an overkill. Also, this is following the pattern of the OP, to show an example. As pointed out in my answer: "Of course, for a real-world code, you will probably want to use more descriptive names to make the code more comprehensible." So for example, `hover1` would be replaced with `hoverLogo` and `hover2` with `hoverHelpIcon`. But it's difficult to think of a better name when you do not know what it's representing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the state of item which you have hovered that's for sure

```js
const { Component, useState, useEffect } = React;

class HoverExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseHover = this.handleMouseHover.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isHovering: false,
      values: ['hello', 'hello2'],
      value: 'hello'
    };
  }

  handleMouseHover({target: {dataset: {id}}}) {
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        ...state,
        isHovering: !state.isHovering,
        value: state.values[id]
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          data-id="0"
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
        >
          Hover Me
        </div>
        <div
          data-id="1"
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseHover}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseHover}
        >
          Hover Me2
        </div>
        {this.state.isHovering && <div>{this.state.value}</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HoverExample />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: An important note about this code is that the component state is coupled to the `data-id` attribute. Should you add the `handleMouseHover` to a node which is missing the attribute, the code will fail. Also, it's connecting the UI data to the state. IMO a better way would be to build a map of id -> isHovering and then determine what value to show in the render function, by checking `this.state.isHoveringMap[id]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the context text as shown in example. This is working code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


// Drive this using some configuration. You can set based on your requirement.
export const HOVER_Hello1 = "Hello1";
export const HOVER_Hello2 = "Hello2";

class HoverExample extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleMouseHover = this.handleMouseHover.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isHovering: false,
            contextText: ""
        };
    }

    handleMouseHover = (e, currentText) => {
        this.setState({
            isHovering: !this.state.isHovering,
            contextText: currentText
        });
    }

    toggleHoverState(state) {
        //
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div
                    onMouseEnter={e => this.handleMouseHover(e, HOVER_Hello1)}
                    onMouseLeave={e => this.handleMouseHover(e, HOVER_Hello1)}

                >
                    Hover Me
        </div>
                <div
                    onMouseEnter={e => this.handleMouseHover(e, HOVER_Hello2)}
                    onMouseLeave={e => this.handleMouseHover(e, HOVER_Hello2)}
                >
                    Hover Me2
        </div>
                {this.state.isHovering && <div>{this.state.contextText}</div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HoverExample;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the whole point is about linking dynamically messages to JSX-element you're hovering, you may store that binding (e.g. within an object).

Upon rendering, you simply pass some anchor (e.g. `id` property of corresponding object) within a custom attribute (`data-*`), so that later on you may retrieve that, look up for the matching object, put linked message into state and render the message.

Following is a quick demo:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const data = [
  {id:0, text: 'Hover me', message: 'Thanks for hovering'},
  {id:1, text: 'Hover me too', message: 'Great job'}
]      
      
class HoverableDivs extends Component {
  state = {
    messageToShow: null
  }
  
  enterHandler = ({target:{dataset:{id:recordId}}}) => {
    const  {message} = this.props.data.find(({id}) => id == recordId)
    this.setState({messageToShow: message})
  }
  
  leaveHandler = () => this.setState({messageToShow: null})
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.data.map(({text,id}) => (
            <div 
              key={id}
              data-id={id}
              onMouseEnter={this.enterHandler}
              onMouseLeave={this.leaveHandler}
            >
              {text}
            </div>
          ))
        }
        {
          this.state.messageToShow && <div>{this.state.messageToShow}</div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}   

render (
  <HoverableDivs {...{data}} />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```